# UIWebView, simply select "actual" font in css, not just family?

Tags: ios, css, swift, uiwebview

In iOS, using UIWebView, I load this short text file
and then display it in a UIWebView. (`loadHTMLString`)

```
<html><head><style type='text/css'>
body
{
font-family:'Source Sans Pro';
font-size:12pt;
}
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
</style></head>
<body leftmargin=0 topmargin=0>
example text...
</body></html>
```

Here are the 12 "actual" font names installed (`print(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName("Source Sans Pro"))`)

> ["SourceSansPro-BoldIt", "SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt", "SourceSansPro-ExtraLight", "SourceSansPro-Semibold", "SourceSansPro-Bold", "SourceSansPro-Black", "SourceSansPro-Regular", "SourceSansPro-Light", "SourceSansPro-BlackIt", "SourceSansPro-It", "SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt", "SourceSansPro-LightIt"]

Now in the UIWebView

```
body
{
font-family:'Source Sans Pro';
font-size:12pt;
}
```

That works perfectly; the regular `Source Sans Pro` font appears.

But. Quite simply,how the hell do I tell the css to use "ExtraLight", "BlackIt" and so on?

## How to choose a specific one of the 12 fonts???

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the actual font names in the CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
                margin: 30px;
                font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
                font-size: 12pt;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Black';
                font-size: 16pt;
                font-weight: normal
            }
            .light {
                font-family: 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Normal Text</p>
        <p class="light">Light Text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

One side note: When you work with fonts that provide a 'real' bold font face it is a good idea to remove the 'artificial' bold font-weight as it makes the already bold font even bolder which does look ugly. (That's why I added `font-weight: normal` to the `h1` selector)

Comment: It's in a UIWebView.

Comment: How does your HTML / CSS look like now?

Comment: **Thanks a million!**  Sent a bounty.  @joern

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks, glad I could help!